# See if a string converts to a double in C

Tags: c

I'm starting with C and I have to check if the argument of the main function is a double. I'm trying to use strtod, but it gives me some trouble. So my main looks like this:

```
    int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    if (!(strtod(argv[1], NULL)) /*trouble is with this line*/
       exit(EX_USAGE);
    else{
    /*some code*/
    }
    return(0);   
    }
```

I have used strtod to parse argv[1] to double (no problem there), but the problem is when argv[1] is not a double, so it obviusly can't be parsed.
Any ideas?

Comment: `strtod` has two arguments. Figure out what the second one is for. Use it to your advantage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtod()` has a second argument that is a pointer to a char pointer. If it isn't `NULL` it will write to that pointer the address in the string where it stopped converting because the rest is not a valid floating point number representation.

If the whole string converted correctly then obviously that pointer will point to the end of the string. The conversion should look like this, with out of range check thrown in for good measure:

```
char *endptr;
double result;

errno = 0;
result = strtod(string, &endptr);
if (errno == ERANGE) {
    /* value out of range */
}
if (*endptr != 0) {
    /* incomplete conversion */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

strtod is for converting string(char array) to double. If the input is not a valid or if the input is valid ZERO or if the input is white spaces then the function returns ZERO.

Comment: That does not work. It also returns zero if the string contains a valid representation of zero. It returns a value different than zero if only part of the string is a valid representation of a floating point number.

Comment: ofcourse!! I will be precise when answering next time onwards.

Answer (score 0):

You have everything you need in the man:

> **NAME**
>
> ```
>    strtod, strtof, strtold - convert ASCII string to floating-point
>    number
> ```
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    #include <stdlib.h>
>
>    double strtod(const char *nptr, char **endptr);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> ```
>   The strtod(), strtof(), and strtold() functions convert the ini‐
>   tial portion of the string pointed to by nptr to double, float,
>   and long double representation, respectively.
> ```
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> ```
>    These functions return the converted value, if any.
>
>    If endptr is not NULL, a pointer to the character after the last
>    character used in the conversion is stored in the location ref‐
>    erenced by endptr.
>
>    If no conversion is performed, zero is returned and the value of
>    nptr is stored in the location referenced by endptr.
> ```

I found this last sentence particularly interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious, but you're not checking `argc` to ensure that you have a parameter to parse. You should be doing something like this:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        exit(EX_USAGE);
    }
    double arg1 = strtod(argv[1], NULL);
    if (arg1==0 && strcmp(argv[1], "0")!=0) {
        exit(EX_USAGE);
    }
    /* some code */
}
```